# What should be done with answer to a question posted in comments?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

I just encountered a posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227830/266531) that wasn't the answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override) but was instead an answer to an extended question asked by a third user Henrique Foletto in a comment for the accepted answer. Both the accepted answer and the second answer for the comment were posted by the same user, 'Ratnakar - Store Apps'. The second answer is quite popular and received a bounty from the user Foletto, the one who asked the question in a comment.

It seems wrong to me to have a second answer to a comment's question. The comment should be its own question and the second answer should be transferred to that question. The user answering the questions certainly did some nice work coming up with two good solutions and should get credit and the bounty. But it's confusing that there is a popular answer posted for a problem not really answering to the page's original question.

Can or should anything be done? I made comments on the two questions in hopes that the user posting answers will remedy, but I doubt they will.

The question that I'm talking about is [WooCommerce: Add product to cart with price override?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327251/woocommerce-add-product-to-cart-with-price-override).

In the accepted answer there is this comment

> Hey, could you please give me an example on how to make it work? I
>   want to add the product with ID 598 to cart with an overrided price. I
>   tried your code but don't know where should I put the product ID.
>   Thank you. –  Henrique Foletto Jan 16 '14 at 13:02

This comment is then answered again by the same user 'Ratnakar - Store Apps' who has the accepted answer. And this answer is fairly popular and was awarded a bounty by the commenter.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21227830/266531

Comment: _"Can or should anything be done?"_ What makes you think this needs an action?

Comment: Well, I'm on the fence. Which is why I thought it would be interesting to hear what others think.

Comment: Posting more than one answer is a supported and valid scenario.  It doesn't often make sense to do so but clearly in this case the other user adding the bounty and extending the ask kinda messed it up.  Fixing it now isn't possible, he can't delete the post with answer mark and deleting the one with the bounty after merging would make him lose the bounty.

Comment: If someone asks you something, you don't run away, then release a movie based on a subject you talked about and provide an answer in it. No, you just answer them, if you can. Why are you trying to make it more difficult than it needs to be? If a (follow-up) question is asked in comments, answer it in comments, otherwise, if it's unrelated, or very different from the original question, tell them to ask a new question.

Comment: Typically, I advise them to make it an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you see an interesting question and answer in comments, you're more than welcome to post a new question, asking the question that was asked in comments, and posting as an answer the answer that you saw in the comments.

Make sure that you use citations as appropriate to indicate which content in your new question and answer is your own original contribution and which is the work of others.

If you would like to mark either post as Community Wiki, to indicate that the content is primarily not your own original contributions (if in fact you add little to no original content), you can, but you are not *obligated* to do so.

Of course, if you don't think that the question and/or its answer is of sufficient quality to merit being asked as a new question, you should naturally refrain from posting that content.

---

If you want to simply comment to the user(s) in question and ask them to post a new question/answer, you're welcome to do that as well.

Answer (score 7):

Don't answer questions posted in comments.

Instruct the OP to post a new question.

Then there is no problem.